# Frame real size with OO manners

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am just trying to program a Pong game with very good OO manners. In my 3rd class I already face the first problem.

Here is my code until now:

Pong.java

```
package PongOO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pong {

    public static final int AREA_WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int AREA_HEIGHT = 700;

    public Pong() {
    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame("Pong");
        PongPanel panel = new PongPanel();
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        guiFrame.setSize(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT);
        guiFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.start();
    }
}
```

PongPanel.java

```
package PongOO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PongPanel extends JPanel {

    private Renderer renderer;

    public PongPanel() {
        initPanel();

        this.renderer = new Renderer();
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        this.setSize(Pong.AREA_WIDTH,Pong.AREA_HEIGHT);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //renderer.drawBackground(g);
        //renderer.drawField(g);
    }
}
```

Renderer.java

```
package PongOO;

import java.awt.*;

public class Renderer {

    public Renderer() {

    }

    public void drawBackground(Graphics g) {
        //draw background
        //need original size of JFrame with
        //frame.getContentPane().getWidth();
    }

    public void drawField(Graphics g) {

    }
}
```

First of all does it seems good until now? Not sure if I should define the Jframe as private property or just let it in the constructor as it is now?

My actual problem is, that I want to take all the drawing (since a class like paddle or ball should not know how its getting painted) in an extra class called Renderer. But I cant just take the static variables AREA_WIDTH and AREA_HEIGHT because of the border of the JFrame it will give me different values. So I need to write a method like

```
public int getFrameWidth() {
    return frame.getContentPane().getWidth();
}
```

But I dont know where or how I should declare that method. Since my frame variable is in constructor and I also cant use this method in other classes because its not static. But if I make my Jframe static it results with different errors and I also think thats not the good OO way to go.

Comment: you already have Aread width and Area height variables in Pong class

Comment: as I already wrote I can't use them, because they dont give me the actual size of the content but with borders

Answer (score 1):

Your pong class can have few more variables like REAL_WIDTH and REAL_HEIGHT.
Which can be provided with values in the Pong 's class start method.

```
package PongOO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pong {

    public static final int AREA_WIDTH = 700;
    public static final int AREA_HEIGHT = 700;
     **public static final int REAL_WIDTH ;
     public static final int REAL_HEIGHT ;**
    public Pong() {
    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame("Pong");
        PongPanel panel = new PongPanel();
        **REAL_WIDTH=guiFrame.getContentPane().getWidth();
        REAL_HEIGHT=guiFrame.getContentPane().getHeight();**
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        guiFrame.setSize(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT);
        guiFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pong pong = new Pong();
        pong.start();
    }
}
```

Now you can use these variables where you want.

Comment: Oops i missed that you used start instead of Pong constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JPanel` knows its own size, and that is what should be relevant.

You may modify the methods of your renderer to take those dimensions, e.g

```
public void drawBackground(Graphics g, int width, int height)
```

then

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    renderer.drawBackground(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
    renderer.drawField(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

You may obvisouly also pass the width and height directly to the constructor, but in this case a subsequent resize of the frame (and the panel) won't be taken into account  :

```
this.renderer = new Renderer(getWidth(), getHeight())
```

Comment: That worked for this specific case, but what to do if I need the width and height in another class? I am still facing the same problem then.